# R lsmeans adjust multiple comparison

Tags: r, logistic-regression, posthoc, lsmeans

I used lme4 to run a mixed effects logistig regression (by calling glmer) in R and now I am trying to do post-hoc comparisons. As they are pairwise, Tukey should be OK,but I would like to manually adjust for how many tests the correction should be made - now it is made for 12 tests, but I am only intersted in 6 comparisons.

My code looks like this so far

```
    for (i in seq_along(logmixed_ranks)) {
    print(lsmeans(logmixed_ranks[[i]], pairwise~rating_ranks*indicator_var, adjust="tukey"))
    }
```

Somehow I may need to use the following but I am not sure how.

```
      p.adjust(p, method = p.adjust.methods, n = length(p))
```

Can anybody help?
Thanks!
Laura

Comment: I suggest to use `glht` from  package multcomp: http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/multcomp/docs/glht

Comment: thanks - does it work with the interaction term though? I cannot figure that out (it only works without the interaction for me)... thanks!

Comment: Assuming your IVs are all factors, you could just reparameterize the model, e.g., from `z ~ x * y + (1|g)` to `i <- interaction(x, y); z ~ i + (1|g)`. That's what I usually do.

Comment: thanks, works for well for me with this interaction term. How would you adjust for multiple testing? (i.e., 6 test but I get more contrasts) - is the default, single-step, fine? Thanks!

Comment: `glht` allows you to specify exactly which comparisons you want to test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There must be a reason you want to adjust for only 6 comparisons, and I'm guessing is it is because you want to break down the comparisons you're doing conditionally on one of the factors. This is easy to do using `lsmeans`:

```
lsmeans(logmixed_ranks[[i]], 
    pairwise ~ rating_ranks | indicator_var, adjust = "tukey")
```

or

```
lsmeans(logmixed_ranks[[i]], 
    pairwise ~ indicator_var | rating_ranks, adjust = "tukey")
```

By the way, if you use `adjust = "mvt"`, you will obtain exactly the same adjustments that `glht` uses for its single-step procedure. So I believe the only `glht` features not supported by `lsmeans` are the multi-step tests.

I'm puzzled by why you have a list of `glmer` objects, but that does not seem germane to my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Both answers (i.e., one answer and one comment) helped a lot, both differently.